# Adding functionality for autofill suggestion on text input in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, autocomplete, textfield, django-autocomplete-light

I have tried several ways to add autocomplete/autofill suggestion functionality on text input. I have set a list 'names' for which I want autofill suggestions when being searched. I have tried three different codes for the same. I am facing problem in the three of them.

First code I got from pypi.org (https://pypi.org/project/fast-autocomplete/). It has library named fast-autocomplete. I tried using it but the problem I am facing here is that it is not giving me real-time autocomplete suggestions.

```
from fast_autocomplete import AutoComplete
words = {'book': {}, 'burrito': {}, 'pizza': {}, 'pasta':{}}
autocomplete = AutoComplete(words=names)

autocomplete.search(input('Type the word \n'), max_cost=3, size=3)
```

The output coming, is that when I type in the input, it is not giving me realtime suggestions. Once I have entered the word, then it is displaying the suggestions. I want the suggestions to be displayed realtime based on list.

[image]

[image]

This is the second example for the same

[image]

[image]

The second code I tried was from pythonbasics.org (https://pythonbasics.org/pyqt-auto-complete/). Here I am unable to get the desired output.

This is the second code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        # auto complete options                                                 
        names = ["Apple", "Alps", "Berry", "Cherry" ]
        completer = QCompleter(names)

        # create line edit and add auto complete                                
        self.lineedit = QLineEdit()
        self.lineedit.setCompleter(completer)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit, 0, 0)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
screen = Window()
screen.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In this the undesirable output is coming. I am getting autocomplete suggestions for words in the list 'names' but I am unable to access it. Only suggestions are coming but when I want to click, nothing is happening. Once clicked, I want to get it stored in a variable which I can access later. I have given the ouput for your perusal.

[image]

Here in this image, when I typed A, I am getting autofill suggestions as Alps or Apple which I want but when I click it, nothing happens. This happens when i click it:

[image]

I have clicked apple and nothing happens, I don't know where Apple is getting stored or how it is functioning exactly. Once clicked, I want further operations to be performed.

In the third code, I am getting a layout from which I can add my own words and later on, I am getting suggestions depending on the words added by me. I want it to connect to my list but I am unable to do so.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QTextEdit, QLineEdit, QCompleter
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel, QFont

class AppDemo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(1200, 800)

        fnt = QFont('Open Sans', 12)

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        # input field
        self.input = QLineEdit()
        self.input.setFixedHeight(50)
        self.input.setFont(fnt)
        self.input.editingFinished.connect(self.addEntry)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.input)

        self.model = QStandardItemModel()
        completer = QCompleter(self.model, self)
        self.input.setCompleter(completer)
        

        self.console = QTextEdit()
        self.console.setFont(fnt)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.console)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

    def addEntry(self):
        entryItem = self.input.text()
        self.input.clear()
        self.console.append(entryItem)

        if not self.model.findItems(entryItem):
            self.model.appendRow(QStandardItem(entryItem))


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
demo = AppDemo()
demo.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

In the above image, an empty layout is appearing through which I can add my own word through input field and later on it will give me recommendations based on those words.

[image]

I have added 3 words and now it will give me recommendations based on them.

[image]

[image]

Since I have added Apple and Banana, it is  giving me recommendation based on them, I want it to connect it to my own list which can be searched. I don't want any word to be added but only require autofill/autocomplete functionality based on list for text field input. Just like how Google works. Once I get my word based on autocomplete suggestions, I want to click it and get my desired data displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works as a minimal solution. You can define a list like self.word_list and it can recommend you the words of your choosing.

```
class AppDemo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.word_list=["apple","banana","question"]
        self.resize(1200, 800)

        fnt = QFont('Open Sans', 12)

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        # input field
        self.input = QLineEdit()
        self.input.setFixedHeight(50)
        self.input.setFont(fnt)
        self.input.editingFinished.connect(self.addEntry)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.input)

        self.model = QStandardItemModel()
        completer = QCompleter(self.word_list, self)
        self.input.setCompleter(completer)
        

        self.console = QTextEdit()
        self.console.setFont(fnt)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.console)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

    def addEntry(self):
        entryItem = self.input.text()
        self.input.clear()
        self.console.append(entryItem)

        if not self.model.findItems(entryItem):
            self.word_list.appendRow(QStandardItem(entryItem))


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
demo = AppDemo()
demo.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is not providing the exact help. Can you help me with the other 2 codes, if that's possiblle.